# Pandas, conditional filtering and multiplication

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, filtering

I have 2 df as shown in the pics

```
[df1][1]
[df2][2]
```

I would like to write a function where:

I will obtain values from `df1['mscm/d']` based on the condition ->

```
(df1['day_of_week] == 'Saturday') & (df1['Season'] == 'summer'))
```

and create a dataframe to store each value from `df1` multiplied by the entire column of `df2['Smr Sat']`

In essence I would like to filer values of df1 based on day and season and multiply each df1 value by the entire row of the corresponding season and day from df2.

Answer (score 0):

```
oneday=df_one['da_of_week']=='saturday'
some_val=df_two['something']==oneday

value=df_two[some_val]
```

i hope this will help. getting value form 1st df then search it form 2nd df